# Куча была повреждена, код срабатывает через раз

Tags: c

Написал такой код

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define FILE_NAME "cnfg.txt"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char** delete_f;
} config;

void create(config* var, FILE* file)
{
    var->delete_f = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));

    char check[3];
    int idx = 0;
    while ((fscanf(file, "%c", &check[0])) == 1)
    {
        fseek(file, -1, SEEK_CUR);
        var->delete_f = (char**)realloc(var->delete_f, idx + 3);
        (var->delete_f)[idx++] = (char*)malloc(20); 
        fgets((var->delete_f)[idx - 1], 20, file);
    }
}

int main()
{
    config var;
    var.delete_f = NULL;

    FILE* file = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");

    create(&var, file);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Но работает, к сожалению, он только через раз. Насколько я понимаю все дело в realloc, потому что, когда я изначально задаю константную величину, работает все хорошо, как только меняю на realloc код начинает очень странно себя вести, то компилируется, то нет. Вылезает ошибка повреждена куча.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как есть

```c
void create(config* var, FILE* file)
{
    // выделили размер под один указатель char*
    var->delete_f = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));

    char check[3];
    int idx = 0;
    while ((fscanf(file, "%c", &check[0])) == 1)
    {
        fseek(file, -1, SEEK_CUR);
        // перевыделили память под idx + 3 байт. Т.е. на первой итерации сюда
        // даже не влезет один элемент char*
        var->delete_f = (char**)realloc(var->delete_f, idx + 3);
        // получили ошибку доступа
        (var->delete_f)[idx++] = (char*)malloc(20); 
        fgets((var->delete_f)[idx - 1], 20, file);
    }
}
```

Как должно быть

```c
void create(config* var, FILE* file)
{
    char check[3];
    int idx = 0;
    while ((fscanf(file, "%c", &check[0])) == 1)
    {
        fseek(file, -1, SEEK_CUR);
        // перевыделили память под (idx + 1) элементов char*
        var->delete_f = (char**)realloc(var->delete_f, (idx + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        // для последнего элемента выделили 20 байт
        (var->delete_f)[idx] = (char*)malloc(20); 
        fgets((var->delete_f)[idx], 20, file);
        idx++
    }
}
```

И по завершению программы нужно будет не забыть освободить всю выделенную память и закрыть файл

Comment: Да, вы правы! Весь день мучался, спасибо большое)